# Unexpected 's' in json When

Tags: php, json, postman

i try to build restAPI
when i check my code on postMan i got error that data incomplete

this is my code for create file

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

include_once 'database.php';
include_once 'inquery.php';
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();
$product = new Inquery($db);
$jsn = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($jsn);
if(
    !empty($data->enqType) &&
    !empty($data->title) &&
    !empty($data->deptid) &&
    !empty($data->enq_body)&&
    !empty($data->taskPriority)
){
    $t = time();
    $product->enqType = $data->enqType;
    $product->title = $data->title;
    $product->deptid = $data->deptid;
    $product->enq_body = $data->enq_body;
    $product->taskPriority = $data->taskPriority;
    $product->addedDate = $t;
    $product->addedBy = 0;
    if($product->create()){
        http_response_code(201);
        echo json_encode(array("message" => "Product was created."));
    } else{
        http_response_code(503);
        echo json_encode(array("message" => "Unable to create product."));
    }
}
else{
    http_response_code(400);
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Unable to create product. Data is incomplete."));
}?>
```

this is my json file that contains what i need

```
{
"title" : "title1",
"enqType" : 1,
"deptid" : 3,
"enq_body" : "some text",
"taskPriority" : 1}
```

i try all things, i see that this code dosen't accept string 
in my checks i recived this errors :

- unexpected 's' in the image shared below:

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to decode the already valid json ? Seems like so. You don't need to do `json_decode($jsn);` as you are already reading a valid json from file.

Comment: @NareshKumar and valid json should be decoded to php object/array.

Comment: i got now 
Status: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: {
    "message": "Unable to create product. Data is incomplete."
}

Comment: do a `print_r($data);` and see what is missing in `$data`. If you're getting `{ "message": "Unable to create product. Data is incomplete." } ` then there mist be something empty of the values checked in if statement `if(
    !empty($data->enqType) &&
    !empty($data->title) &&
    !empty($data->deptid) &&
    !empty($data->enq_body)&&
    !empty($data->taskPriority)
)`